# Custom Icon with jQuery IAS plugin?

Tags: jquery-ias

I'm using the jQuery IAS plugin with the spinner extension to load posts from a paginated list of links. The [docs](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/extension-spinner.html) specify `src: '<image source>'` as a way to link a custom loading gif, but I'd like to use an icon font spinner like [this](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#spinning). Anyone know how I can achieve this without hacking the src file?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming (at Stack Overflow, we are all about hacking the source files). Perhaps you should ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Haha. Ok @jww. I want to maintain compatibility with future versions so I don't have to re-hack on updates is all.

Comment: You need custom CSS with the class `ias-spinner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have already installed font awesome. Then you can [override the html snippet](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/extension-spinner.html#html) for the spinner like this:

```
ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension({
  html: '<div class="ias-spinner" style="text-align: center;"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></div>'
}));
```

Comment: Thank you. For the record I got it working with @RubenKazumov's suggestion, however this is the correct answer b/c as mentioned, the icon font is already loaded and this approach avoids double-writing class attributes. Great plugin btw :)